# Workbook.CheckIn always produces an error the first time it's called? (x-posted on StackOverflow)

Tags: 2007, excel, vba

This question is cross-posted on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711303/workbook-checkin-always-produces-an-error-the-first-time-its-called/29736233#29736233).

I have some workbooks stored in a document library on Sharepoint 2007.  I want to check out a workbook, modify it, and check it back in.

Using the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub test()

Dim bk As Workbook
Dim path As String

path = "http://sharepoint/sites/test/TEST_Relink.xlsm"

If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(path) Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.CheckOut path
    DoEvents
    Set bk = Workbooks.Open(path, False)
    bk.Sheets("test").Range("h1").Value = "modified " & Now
    DoEvents
    Sleep 10000
    bk.checkIn True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If


End Sub
```

The `bk.checkIn` call always produces the following run-time error:

```
Method 'CheckIn' of object '_Workbook' failed
```

After I go into Debug, I press `F5` to continue and the check-in always occurs successfully.

I added the 10-second delay with `Sleep 10000` because I was thinking that maybe the check-out was taking a while to propagate to the server.  But no matter how much time I set for `Sleep`, this same issue keeps occurring.

I tried using a looped check of `.CanCheckIn` as follows:

```
While Not bk.CanCheckIn
DoEvents
Wend
bk.checkIn True
```

This gave the same error.

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29736233/619177) and got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This post is 7 years old, and I still see a lot of people struggling with this error ("Method 'CheckIn' of object '_Workbook' failed"). I finally found a solution that worked for me.

Instead of executing the check-in in a single line of code (as shown below), **I broke it down into two lines of code,** first saving the file and then checking it in.

Assume "docCheckIn" is a string variable that contains the name of the file you want to check in and "sComment" is also a string variable that contains whatever comment you want to record.

Instead of writing the code like this:

```
    Workbooks(docCheckIn).CheckIn SaveChanges:=True, Comments:=sComment
```

Do this:

```
    Workbooks(docCheckIn).Save
    Workbooks(docCheckIn).CheckIn Comments:=sComment
```